# problem when deploying vuejs app on heroku

Tags: django, vue.js, heroku, web-deployment

I have a vuejs app that calling api from django website. 
I've already deployed django app on heroku successful but when I deploy vuejs and have access to my website. Something went wrong and when I looked at logs, some issues occur.
Here is the logs

```
2020-04-19T14:49:31.711749+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: vue-cli-service: not found
2020-04-19T14:49:31.716381+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-04-19T14:49:31.716381+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2020-04-19T14:49:31.716382+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2020-04-19T14:49:31.716509+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2020-04-19T14:49:31.717484+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! frontend@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
2020-04-19T14:49:31.717565+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2020-04-19T14:49:31.717683+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-04-19T14:49:31.717772+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@0.1.0 serve script.
2020-04-19T14:49:31.717842+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-04-19T14:49:31.725202+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-04-19T14:49:31.725472+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-04-19T14:49:31.725649+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-04-19T14_49_31_718Z-debug.log
2020-04-19T14:49:31.737139+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-04-19T14:49:31.737481+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-04-19T14:49:31.739147+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! frontend@0.1.0 start: `npm run serve`
2020-04-19T14:49:31.739368+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-04-19T14:49:31.739629+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-04-19T14:49:31.739829+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@0.1.0 start script.
2020-04-19T14:49:31.742569+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-04-19T14:49:31.749331+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-19T14:49:31.749332+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-04-19T14:49:31.749333+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-04-19T14_49_31_741Z-debug.log
```

My package.json file

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run serve",
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
```

And I already delete `\dist` in `.gitignore` file

Comment: Stupid question but is vue-cli-service installed ? `npm i @vue/cli` ?

Comment: yes, I know it's stupid. It should be "start": "vue-cli-service serve". I just included every dependencies in devDependencies to dependencies and static.json file. I'm having ```Invalid Host header``` issue after doing those things.